# Maven JdbcTemplate exclusion

Tags: java, spring-jdbc

I would like to use JdbcTemplate to query some very simple values:

```
String sql = "SELECT NAME FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUST_ID = ?";
String name = (String)getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(
        sql, new Object[] { custId }, String.class);
```

So I added the flowing entry to my pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

I see other Jars added

1. spring-tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar
2. spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar
3. spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar

I would like to minimize the jar clash with the host application, and reduce my code footprint,
Out of this list what can I exclude and still letting JdbcTemplate work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't disappoint you but ... none of them is excludable. All of the mentioned jars are needed.

You can check that out by visiting the [dependency respository site itself](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/4.3.7.RELEASE). There you can find all of them (and even more) in the "Compile Dependencies" list.

Or execute `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=org.springframework:spring-core,org.springframework:spring-tx,org.springframework:spring-beans` inside the root of your project to verify it on your own.

The command should give you something like:

```
[INFO] \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 4.3.7.RELEASE)
[INFO]    |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.3.7.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 4.3.7.RELEASE)
[INFO]       +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.3.7.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]       \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.3.7.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
```